# Regex - Remove anchor tags wrapped around img tags

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm currently working on a very large WordPress build that is heavily populated with posts. I've had a request come through where I have to do the following...

Remove all anchor tags that are wrapped around img tags.

For example, I need the following...

```
<a href="some-random-page"><img src="some-radom-image"/></a>
```

To become...

```
<img src="some-random-image"/>
```

Could this at all be done using an SQL update statement that I can run in phpMyAdmin as all WordPress posts are stored in the "posts" table.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: MySQL can't do regex replacement out-of-the box. You could use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` [user defined function](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp), however. See [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/986826/851811).

Comment: Now I just need the REGEX to actually do this lol.

Comment: Or use string manipulation functions such as [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to strip out the anchor part (may require some assumptions on the column's content)

Comment: Just when you're uploading the image to your post via the WP media uploader, under "Attachment Display Settings" and the "Link To" drop-down box, select "None" ... after you do it a couple of times, WP will just default to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so with Dreamweaver. Export your db table. Open in Dreamweaver.

Find the following with "regular expression" option checked.

```
<a href="([^>]*)"><img src="([^>]*)"/></a>
```

Now replace this with:

```
<img src=$2/>
```

Now import the db table back to MySQL.

Comment: Shall give this a try now Harpreet :-)

Comment: you should check if <a> tag has other attributes too. You may look into the Dreamweaver regular expressions. Just give these a try: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html another one is http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html

Comment: I have tried your method of importing the database table into Dreamweaver and I think the following REGEX is even finding what I'm looking for...

    (<a[^>]*)(href=)([^>]*?)(><img[^>]*>(.*?)(</img>)?</a>)

But I have no idea how to remove the anchor tags as the replace section in "Find & Replace" is literal.

Comment: Have successfully solved this issue by using the REGEX posted above and putting "<img src=$2/>" into the replace section of Dreamweaver.

Comment: Sorry typo. I used "<img src=$3/>" in the replace section.

Answer (score 1):

For match use   : `(<a[^<]*>.*?)(<img[^>]*>)([^<]*</a>)`

For replace use : `$2`

Example : http://RegExr.com?37vbk

(replace dummy text in the example with your string)